# How to partially escapeHTML in Ruby (dont escape HTML tags)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-escape-characters

I ned to write a string that could escape both these strings.

```
str = "We couldn't help"
str = "We couldn&#39;t help."
```

I achieved that using

```
CGI.escapeHTML(CGI.unescapeHTML(str))
```

Now however I have a new requirement of accomodating HTML tags as well.

```
str = "We couldn&#39;t help. Check <a href = https://www.google.com>link</a> for help"
```

How can I escape the string except the HTML tags ? So that I can escape all these 3 kinds of strings.

Comment: I learnt from here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/ruby-gem-to-escape-html-tags-that-arent-in-a-whitelist

that we can use CGI.unescapeElement(escaped_str, %w[a img p h]) to escape selected elements. Is there a way to escape any and all HTML elements.

Comment: Why do you think you even need to escape single quotes? It doesn't need to be escaped when its the contents in a text node. It only needs to be escaped if its used in an unquoted attribute and if its used as the boundy for that attribute like for example `foo='&#39;'`. If you want to process and escape HTML you want to use a HTML Parser (Nokogiri) together with a scrubber like Loofah to whitelist the HTML tags. Both are already dependencies in Rails. https://mina86.com/2021/no-you-dont-need-to-escape-that/

Comment: `CGI.escapeElement` is just using a regular expression to process HTML and we all know where that leads. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/544825

Comment: Im dealing with a corpus that has a huge number of strings of the mentioned three categories, and the ouput point unescapes them already. I can touch either of the two. Im in between trying to put forward a proper escaped string to be consumed on the other end.

Comment: Wel if its inputs are syntactically valid HTML then use a HTML parser that actually understands HTML. `Nokogiri::HTML5.fragment(str).to_html`. It won't escape the single quote though as thats not even needed.